# Yii set default options for a custom CGridView

Tags: php, css, class, yii, cgridview

Using PHP framework Yii. As you know, default CGridView table CSS class is `items`. Well I want to change this value. I know it's possible for one specific widget. Like this:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'user-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(),
    'itemsCssClass'=>'gridtablecss',
)); ?>
```

But how to do this for whole Yii application? I mean make default some another class not `items`

Comment: Why don't you make a class that extends CGridView and set some default properties for your project? I'm not sure the config option you are looking for exists natively.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to set some static parameters for each widget then you don't need to extend the class. You can also use Yii's [`widgetFactory`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidgetFactory) component. You can configure it in your `main.php` configuration file.

```
'components' => array(
    // ...

    // Default properties for some widgets
    'widgetFactory' => array(
        'widgets' => array(
            'CGridView' => array(
                'itemsCssClass' => 'gridtablecss'
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another php file in your extensions folder, and name it MyGridView.php:

```
<?php
Yii::import('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView');

class MyGridView extends CGridView {

    public function init() {

        // Set default CSS class
        $this->itemsCssClass = 'gridtablecss';

        // Other modifications, i.e.: Increase page size
        if ($this->dataProvider !== null)
            $this->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 999999;

        parent::init();
    }
}
```

Now instead of using CGridView, you use your new CGridView like this:

```
<?php $this->widget('MyGridView', array(
```

Make sure your **main.php** config file is importing extensions:

```
'import' => array(
    'application.extensions.*',
    ...
),
```

You can also extend CListView (and other similar core Yii classes) the same way.